# What is the name of this subgroup of $S_6$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What is the name of the subgroup of $S_6$ generated by the permutations $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$ and $(1\,4)$?

It describes the symmetries of the edges of the tetrahedron.

EDIT: It describes the symmetries of the edges of the tetrahedron **up to duality**, i.e. vertices are allowed to become faces and vice versa.

I think the order of this group must be 48: Each permutation of the columns and each permutation of the entries within each column of the matrix 
$$\begin{matrix}
1 &2 &3\\
4 &5 & 6
\end{matrix}$$
describes a permutation of the group. Every permutation of the group can be arrived at in this way. For example $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$ is arrived at like this:

$\begin{matrix}
1 &2 &3\\
4 &5 & 6
\end{matrix}\quad \overset{\text{permute columns}}{\longrightarrow} \quad \begin{matrix}
2 &3 &1\\
5 &6 &4
\end{matrix} \quad \overset{\text{permute last column}}{\longrightarrow} \quad \begin{matrix}
2 &3 &4\\
5 &6 &1
\end{matrix} $

That makes $3 ! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!\cdot 2! = 48$ permutations.

**EDIT2**: As pointed out below by Derek Holt, the two permutations $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$ and $(1\,4)$ do not actually generate the group I initially intended.

Comment: Note that (14)(25)(36) is the 3rd power of (123456).

Comment: Oh yes, of course! I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The symmetry group of a tetrahedron does not contain any elements of order $6$ - it is isomorphic to $S_4$ (or $A_4$ if you insist on only orientation-preserving symmetries). Perhaps you should unpack the line "It describes the symmetries of the edges of the tetrahedron".

Comment: (In fact, there is a Wikipedia page about the symmetries of a tetrahedron: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_symmetry).)

Comment: The group generated by those two permutations is $C_2 \wr C_3$ of order $24$. As has been pointed out, it is not equal to the action of the symmetry group of the tetrahedon on edges, which is a subgroup of index $2$ in $C_2 \wr S_3$.

Comment: @Larry Your edit helps - the orders now match up (your permutation group has order $24$, by Derek Holt's comment, while the group you describe has order $24$ as it is an extension of $A_4$ by a cyclic group of order two). Your group will then be on this list: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_groups_of_order_24

Comment: @user1729 Is there a mistake in my argument that the order of the group must be 48?

Comment: @Larry I don't understand your argument. How can the group permute the pairs? And what do you mean by "permute each pair in itself"?

Comment: @user1729 I have tried to make myself clearer.

Comment: @Larry You seem to be assuming that $(14)\neq(41)$, etc. This is false, as $(14)$ just means "swap $1$ and $4$", which is the same thing as "swap $4$ and $1$". Hence, $(14)=(41)$.

Comment: @user1729 I have once more tried to clarify what I mean

Comment: Your argument is almost correct, but the induced action of the group on the columns is not $S_3$ but $C_3$, the cyclic group of order $3$. So the order is $3 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 24$.

Comment: $(6,5,4,3,2,1)$ is just the inverse of $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ so you have not made the group any bigger.

Comment: This feels a bit like "guess what I'm thinking". Perhaps you should start a new question which asks "I believe that *these* permutations generate *this* group. Here is my proof. Is it correct?" (by "*these* permutations" I mean the permutations you give, and by "*this* group" I mean the group you describe). Once the permutations are worked out, only then can we work out what group you are actually looking at.

Answer (score 5):

The first comment would suggest that we have the cyclic group order 6 but I don't think the symmetry group of a tetrahedron can be (isomorphic to) this. I would imagine that it would be generated by elements such as (of the same shape as) $(1,2,3)(4,5,6)$ (rotation around a vertex).

The square of $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is of this shape; it is $(1,3,5)(2,4,6)$ but I can't see how $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is in the edge symmetry group of a tetrahedron. Maybe I am missing something.

So, I think the group generated by $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ and $(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)$ is $C_{6}$ (the latter generator being redundant) but my instinct would be that the edge symmetry group of a tetrahedron is not cyclic.

Linked to that, I can't see how $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is a symmetry of a tetrahedron.

One last question: Is the edge symmetry group of a tetrahedron the same as (isomorphic to) the vertex symmetry group but labelled differently? For a tetrahedron with vertices $a,b,c$ and $d$ the vertex symmetry group would be generated by elements such as $(a,b,c)$ (this is a rotation around $d$).

One last last question: Are you talking about symmetry preserving orientation? (That is what my last point assumed). If so then the symmetry group of a tetrahedron is (isomorphic to) $A_{4}$. If not then it is (isomorphic to) $S_{4}$.

By taking the edge symmetry group you pick out $S_{4}$ or $A_{4}$ (depending on if you want to preserve orientation) as a subgroup of $S_{6}$. If you label via vertices it reads straight of as $S_{4}$ or $A_{4}$.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here - they have simply pointed out an issue with the question, and the OP has (subsequently) corrected their question. So surely +1 not -1...!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment by @GerryMyerson, the $(1\,4)(2\,5)(3\,6)$ is the $3$rd power of $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$. Hence, the subgroup generated by both is simply the subgroup generated by $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$, an element of order $6$. Hence, the subgroup is $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

**UPDATE (since OP changed the question):**

The group clearly has order $12$ and is non-abelian. Hence, we have $3$ options. $A_4$,$D_6$ and $\text{Dic}_3$. Now, $A_4$ doesn't have a subgroup of order $6$. So, we have $2$ options left. Now, $(1\,4)^{-1}(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)(1\,4)=(1\,5\,6\,4\,2\,3) \notin <(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)>$. Hence, it has asubgroup of order $6$ that is not normal i.e. it can't be $\text{Dic}_3$.

Hence, it's the Dihedral group of order $12$ i.e. $D_6$.

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, the group has order $24$. I'll update this answer once I can solve it. Till then, please keep in mind that the answer is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, please see the corrected question

Comment: @Larry I've edited my answer.

Comment: Your update is not correct. In particular, $(14)^{-1}=(14)$ but $(123456)^{-1}(14)(123456)\neq(14)$ (I calculate it to be $(25)$ or $(36)$, depending on how you compose your permutations).

Comment: Also, yes the relators $a^{2n}$ and $x^2=a^n$ hold here, where $n=6$. However, in the dicyclic group it *does not* hold that $a^n=1$ and $x^2=a^n=1$ (which is what happens here - the $6$-cyclic has order $6$, etc.)

Comment: @user1729 Well, this is not $A_4$ either. Then, is it Dihedral group? Let me check. Doesn't seem like though.

Comment: No, its not $A_4$. (What my comments to the questions were saying is that there must be an error/misunderstanding somewhere. The symmetries of a tetrahedron form $A_4$, which contains no element of order $6$. But clearly $(123456)$ has order $6$.)

Comment: @user1729 Let that aside. I just wanna find out what this group is. That seems to be a problem in its own.

Comment: @user1729Does it seem okay now?

Comment: I think "the group clearly has order 12" is incorrect. (Certainly, this is not clear. Also, Derek Holt's comment on the question stated that the group has order $24$. I have not checked, but I am willing to believe him. [Derek Holt is a very believable person. He also is very handy with a computer.])

Comment: As I said in my comment, the group has order $24$ not $12$. And yes I did check iyt by computer!

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you get other data? Such as how many elements of a specific order are there etc?

Comment: Yes I could do that in GAP for example, and you could do that for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Let G be the group generated by $a=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$, $b=(1,4)$. 
The conjugates of $b$ by $a$ and $a^2$ give (3,6)
and (2,5) respectively. So the normal subgroup $Q$ generated by $b$ is elementary abelian of order 8 (isomorphic to $Z_2^3$) and contains $a^3=(1,4)(2,5)(3,6)$. Thus the group generated by G is a cyclic extension of $Q$ by an element of order 3, so it has order 24.

Comment: One can show that there is a subgroup of index 2 isomorphic to $A_4$ and then using https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_groups_of_order_24 the group is easily seen to be the direct product $A_4 \times Z_2$ where the $Z_2$ is the central element $a^3$.